# return dereferenced new - memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I want to know if this causes a memory leak:

```
std::string test() {
    return *(new std::string(""));
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply `return "";`?

Comment: @FredOverflow It was just an example

Comment: A similar question got [a very detailed answer + explanation here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8840302/85371)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's a memory leak. When the function returns, a copy is made of the original string object.

Then the original new'ed pointer falls out of scope and is lost - a leak.

Answer (score 0):

To make it less leaking make it return a reference:

```
std::string& test() {
   return *(new std::string(""));
}
```

Comment: so when I for example have std::string& abc = test(); and I call delete &abc; There won't be any leak ?