# Deallocating memory in C++ vector<T>

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

The following is the best "minimum working example" I can construct for now.  I would like to understand if the following code leaks memory.

```
// Class CTest
class CTest {
  vector<int> Elements;
  CTest (vector<int>&);
  ~CTest ();
};
CTest::CTest (vector<int>& Elements_) {
  this->Elements = Elements_;
}
CTest::~CTest () {
}

// main
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  vector<CTest> V;
  for (auto i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    vector<int> U;
    for (auto j = i; j < i + 5; j++) U.push_back (j);
    V.push_back (*(new CTest (U)));
  }
  // Do whatever
  return 0;
}
```

Am I correct in thinking that since there isn't a corresponding invocation of `delete` for each invocation of `new`, this programme does indeed leak memory?

Comment: Same issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8839943/46642

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Moreover, your code is of the type "trying very hard to get it wrong", since `vector` is already a dynamic container and you have no reason to perform *another* dynamic allocation for your element (just to have it copied).

There are many more ways to screw up. None of those are a particular design problem of C++, but there's simply a limit to what the language can stop you from doing. Some more examples:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    new double;  // leak
    delete static_cast<void*>(&argc);  // doesn't belong to you
    int a = *static_cast<int const *>(0x42); // not a valid pointer

    { T x; x.~T(); }  // call destructor of non-existent object

    { T y; y.~T(); new (static_cast<void*>(&y) T(); }
                   // impossible to recover from exception in T::T()
}
```

Fortunately, it is almost always fairly obvious that you're doing something you're not supposed to.

Comment: Instead of a playbook of other ways to screw up, wouldn't an example of how to correct the code in the Q be a better use of this space?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You mean "how to use `vector`?" Nah, I think the OP knows that.

Comment: "None of those are a particular design problem of C++, but there's simply a limit to what the language can stop you from doing." Naw, it's just that C++ (and most mainstream languages) have a terrible type system. Given a stronger type system it's entirely possible to guarantee, through type checking, that the program contains none of the errors you demonstrate.

Comment: @GManNickG: Perhaps... but can it be done without sacrificing expressiveness? Do you know of a language that doesn't let you write insane things like these but still gives you the same amount of control?

Comment: @KerrekSB: [ATS](http://www.ats-lang.org/), but the use of such type systems for system's programming is still new, so the language is a bit rough to work in. Of course there's things like Haskell and (Dependent) ML, but those aren't system programming languages.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is a memory leak.  `push_back` copies its argument, so the original is lost forever (there is no longer a pointer to it).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct. You don't deallocate the assignments made with new. Also, you don't need dynamic allocation within an already dynamic container.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is leaking but just because you are trying too hard.

Using this code to populate the `V` vector

```
V.push_back(CTest(U));
```

will do what need, without any leaks.

Generally, the standard containers will manage the memory for you (without leaks). You don't have to bother.