# unique_ptr with an API that expects raw pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

After about 10 years of using managed memory and functional languages, I'm finally coming home to C++, and smart pointers are confusing the heck out of me. Half of the documentation out there is still regarding the deprecated `auto_ptr`.

I'm trying to implement this fairly straightforward Bullet ["hello world"](http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Hello_World#Initial_Program) program:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    auto bp = unique_ptr<btBroadphaseInterface>(new btDbvtBroadphase);
    auto cc = unique_ptr<btDefaultCollisionConfiguration>(new btDefaultCollisionConfiguration);
    auto disp = unique_ptr<btDispatcher>(new btCollisionDispatcher(cc));
}
```

The `btCollisionDispatcher` constructor wants a `btCollisionConfiguration*`, but I'm giving it a `unique_ptr` to one instead.

What do I normally want to do in this case? If there's a way to "de-smart" the pointer, something tells me that `unique_ptr` isn't the right smart pointer to use.

[image]

C++ was my language of choice before I moved to other things. It's a little shocking coming back and seeing that all the patterns and practices have completely changed.

Comment: I think the answer depends on `btCollisionDispatcher` does it want to *share* the ownership or will it *take* ownership? If latter - can you not change it to accept the `unique_ptr`? If the former, you'll have to change this to `shared_ptr` and pass that in.

Comment: `disp` will be holding onto `cc` and using it until it's destructed. It expects that you'll use it elsewhere, like when I call the `btWorld` constructor later on, but it doesn't share the pointer outside of its own scope, as far as I can tell.

Comment: It may not be related to your question, but as you say you come from a managed langauge background, just be sure not spam smart pointers too much and always consider automatic storage first. Just a small but important advice, that had to be said.

Comment: "What do I normally want to do in this case?" [Read `std::unique_ptr`'s documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: The best thing you can do coming from managed languages is forget all about `new`!

Comment: @ildjarn C++ was my language of choice before I moved to other things, so `new` is pretty familiar. It's just the smart pointer stuff that's got me stumped.

Comment: My larger point was, automatic storage should suffice 90% of the time. :-]

Comment: @ChristianRau when you say automatic storage, do you mean stack allocation? I'm hearing conflicting opinions on whether or not I should use smart pointers everywhere -- the only thing everyone seems to agree on is not to use them in performance-critical tight loops.

Comment: @ildjarn Hmm okay so if I'm not mistaken, automatic storage is synonymous with stack allocation... wouldn't I be liable to hastening a stack overflow?

Comment: If you manage to get a stack overflow via using automatic storage (as opposed to e.g. deep recursion), I'd be quite surprised. But in that case, increase your stack size and continue avoiding `new` as much as possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a `get()` member function that gives you the raw pointer that is held by the `unique_ptr`. This does not cause the `unique_ptr` to relinquish the ownership, though, so proper cleanup will still happen (careful with storing that raw pointer!).

There is also a `release()` member function, which relinquishes ownership. This means that you're back on dumb pointer land and cleanup is all your responsibility.

I can't fathom why the code is using `new` in the first place and not [just using automatic storage objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839943/why-does-the-use-of-new-cause-memory-leaks-in-c/8840302#8840302), but I'm going to pretend there is a reason...

Comment: Thanks, that compiles. Is get() the idiomatic/correct option in this situation?

Comment: If the code you're passing the pointer to does not take responsibility for cleanup (which looking at the bullet site looks like the case), yes, `get()` is the correct option.

Comment: I take it then that in general if I'm creating and deleting the object, I own it -- so I can use `get()`?

Comment: @Rei Yes, ownership here means "responsibility for cleanup".

Comment: Thanks, that is very useful, especially `release()` is helping me deal with some tricky legacy code.

Answer (score 3):

The [get](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee475590.aspx) member function returns the underling pointer and is fine to use with existing code as long as that code doesn't manage the memory you pass in.