# Memory allocation and releasing memory

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm a newbie using V++ and I've been wondering about some memory behavior.
I wrote similar classes to what is causing me problems. The questions are 
written in the comments of the code.

```
class A
{
private:
    int _number;
public:
    A(int number) : _number(number)
    {}

    const int& getNumber() const
    {
        return _number;
    }

    void setNumber(const int& number)
    {
        _number = number;
    }
}

class B
{
private:
    A _a;
    bool _hasA;

public:
    B() : _hasA(false)
    {}

    B(const A & a) : _a(a), _hasA(true)
    {}

    void setA(const A & a)
    {
        _a = a;
    }

    const A& getA() const
    {
        return _a;
    }

    const bool hasA() const
    {
        return _hasA;
    }

    void removeA()
    {
        // ??
    }
}

int main()
{
    A a(5);

    B b1; // Is the A space allocated even if no value is affected to it ?
    B b2(a);

    b1.setA(b2.getA()); // I actually want to move "a" from b2 to b1 without leaving it in b2
    b1.removeA(); // Do I need to write a removeA() function and how would it be?
}
```

`b1.setA(b2.getA());` copies `A` into `b1` too instead of moving it.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:** To answer those who are confused like I just was:

Me : I just understood that when instanciating b1 it needed the `A::A()` constructor. I thought it'd be like "null" or something if I created `b1` without instantiating `_a`.

Zac Howland: @SanjamX I see your confusion now. In managed languages, (most) everything is a pointer, so if you do not instantiate it (e.g. A a instead of `A a = new A()`), it is just a null pointer. In C/C++, if you declare something as A a, you instantiated it "on the stack". It is an automatic variable that will be deallocated when it goes out of scope. You are still instantiating it, however. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823454/declaring-a-variable-vs-dynamically-assigning-memory-to-a-variable-in-c) may help you understand better.

Comment: Have you tried to compile it? (hint: it won't compile, there are several errors) Note: `B b1();` is a function declaration ("most vexing parse"); either use C++11's `B b1{};` or just `B b1;`.

Comment: I don't see any point in your code, where it's necessary to free allocated memory? It will be all done pretty well on the stack?

Comment: with b1.setA(b2.getA()); A will be copied to b1. Will they share the same pointer? I want to move A to b1 and not copy it. In other terms, I want it to be deleted from b2.

Comment: May be `removeA()` could just get off with setting `_hasA` to false, and assign `_a` to some reasonable default value (if that's needed at all). The design smells somehow though!

Comment: _'Will they share the same pointer?'_ It's **copied** ...!!

Comment: This isn't really "the design", I just wrote this code to express the allocation problems I was having. As I wrote in the first question, when declaring, will it allocate space in the memory for A even though it isn't instanciated ?

Comment: @SanjamX _'to express the allocation problems'_ The code you show **has no allocation problems**!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Exception safety is one of the big design smells with the 2-step approach.

Comment: @SanjamX On the line you asked about, it won't allocate anything because it isn't declaring a variable, but a function.  If you were to have `B b1;`, it would allocate space for both an `A` and a `bool` (which is what you have in class `B`) because you *are* instantiating it.  Are you coming from a managed language background by chance?

Comment: Indeed, I am. And the b1() was a mistake, I edited it when it was notified to me.

Comment: I just understood that when instanciating b1 it needed the A::A() constructor. I thought it'd be like "null" or something if I created b1 without instanciating _a.

Comment: @SanjamX I see your confusion now.  In managed languages, (most) everything is a pointer, so if you do not instantiate it (e.g. `A a` instead of `A a = new A()`), it is just a null pointer.  In C/C++, if you declare something as `A a`, you instantiated it "on the stack".  It is an automatic variable that will be deallocated when it goes out of scope.  You are **still** instantiating it, however.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823454/declaring-a-variable-vs-dynamically-assigning-memory-to-a-variable-in-c) may help you understand better.

Comment: I can see that now. I'll read the question. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
B b1();
```

That does not do what you think it does.  It is declaring a function `b1` that takes no parameters and returns a `B`.

```
b1.setA(b2.getA());
b1.removeA();
```

Because of the previous situation, the 2 lines above will give you a compiler error.

The "move" you are asking about will actually be a copy (in this case).  You can use the C++11 move semantics to do an actual move, but it is entirely unnecessary with the current code.  Alternatively, you can change your class to do a move using pointers (which could potentially be useful) - which would use `std::unique_ptr<A> _a`, instead of `A _a`.

Comment: the "move" from std will swap values between what's in b1::_a and b2::_a ? What if I want to delete what's b2::_a ?

Comment: @SanjamX There's nothing to _'swap'_ actually!! Declare an appropriate move constructor otherwise.

Comment: @SanjamX No, it will not swap them.  If you move it, it is moved.  I think you would be better served to use the `std::unique_ptr` solution as there is no need to move anything in your current code.