# is this code memory leak in c++?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have this class:

```
class Base{
     private:
        char *message;
     public:
        Base(string message`);
        ~Base();    
};
```

Edited: sorry, i forgot giving my constructor!
When i implement the destructor like below:

```
Base::Base(string message1){
     message = new char[message1.size() + 1]
     message[message1.size()] = '\0';
     memcpy(message, message1.c_str(), message.size());
}
Base::~Base(){
     delete message;  
}
```

sometime the system go wrong with `stop working` error, but if instead of `delete message`, i use `message = NULL`, everything  will be alright! So, if I just declare `message = NULL` in my destructor, does my program get memory leak?

Comment: This sounds incredibly fishy, but there's no way to answer it without a more complete example (namely, what happens in the constructor?).

Comment: what do you do in the constructor?

Comment: I'm curious - what's *"stop working"* error?

Comment: Short answer: use `std::string` all the way.

Comment: actually, i don't know what error i got! Just a pop up windows form with "stop working"! and i included `using name space std` in my `.h` file!

Comment: Must I state the obvious? OK. This code cannot possibly cause a memory leak, as it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's absolutely no reason to use `new` here. The constructor takes a `std::string` and then *manually* copies its contents into a new dynamically allocated array of `char`. This is completely worthless. If instead, the constructor simply copied it into another `std::string`, the `std::string` copy constructor would do the same, but with lots of free benefits: exception-safety, [no memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839943/why-does-the-use-of-new-cause-memory-leaks-in-c/8840302#8840302), and [proper copy semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

```
class Base{
     private:
        string message;
     public:
        Base(string message);
        // maybe a virtual destructor is desirable if this is a polymorphic base class
        // virtual ~Base() {}
};

Base::Base(string message1) : message(message1) {}
```

Answer (score 5):

You problem is using `delete` on something created with `new[]`. It needs a `delete[] message` to deallocate the string properly.

Setting the pointer to NULL just masks the problem, and *does* leak the memory.

Comment: Bingo, and +1. This is the correct answer to the "sometime the system go wrong with stop working error" problem. Using `delete` rather than `delete[]` to release memory allocated via `new[]` is undefined behavior, and setting the pointer to NULL (and why bother?) leaks.

Answer (score 2):

There *is* a memory leak. You allocate a `char` array, so you need to delete it appropriately, like this:

```
Base::~Base(){
     delete[] message;  
}
```

It is irrelevant if you set the pointer to NULL, the pointer itself is deallocated anyway after the destructor is called.

Answer (score 1):

With the code shown here, there's no memory leak. But, affecting `NULL` to a pointer doesn't delete it in any case. You just loose the reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use `delete`? You aren't allocating memory on a heap, you are just creating a pointer. Unless, however you're allocating memory on the heap in the constructor, which we can't know considering you have chosen not to share the code...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a memory leak if you do not `delete` the memory dynamically allocated by `new` in your constructor.

You have to use `delete[] message`

Answer (score 1):

There is a memory leak because by simply doing message = NULL, you've only voided the address of the pointer. The contents that were held in memory still exist and have not been deleted.