# Instantiating a new instance of a variable

Tags: c++, mfc

I have two classes. In the main class I have a process that is step by step and can be stepped though, I have implemented this as a state machine. To help keep the machine easy/friendly I created another class that holds information about the current state of the machine. In the main class I then added a reference to it as such

```
CAnimateMachine *m_AniMach;
```

After some actions happen I call a function in the main class to instantiate variables within my state machine object. Each call to this function `AniInit()` should basically "reset" the state machine by instantiating the variables to the "initial state".

My issue is I am not sure how to instantiate my `m_AniMach` properly. I am used to C# where I can just do

```
m_AniMach = new CAnimateMachine();
```

to "erase" the old object and instantiate a new one. Though, from [what I have read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248703/creating-an-instance-of-class), I can not be so cavalier in C++. What is the proper way to "re-instantiate" this variable in my init method?

Could I use the new operator `m_AniMach = new CAnimateMachine()` and then in the main class' deconstrutor do `delete &m_AniMach`?

**EDIT:** *juanchopanza's* answer makes sense to me. Though I keep getting an error when trying to compile. I am not exactly sure what the error is trying to tell me, I think it is telling me that my class isn't public when it is? I reviewed the [C2248 MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsbce2bh.aspx) article but I do not see how it relates to my situation.

```
error C2248: 'CObject::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'
include\afx.h(562) : see declaration of 'CObject::operator ='
include\afx.h(532) : see declaration of 'CObject'
occurred in the compiler generated function 'CAnimateMachine &CAnimateMachine::operator =(const CAnimateMachine &)'
```

Here is my `CAnimateMachine` class

```
class CAnimateMachine
{
public:
    CAnimateMachine();

    int startX,startY;
};
```

And this is how I instantiate it

```
m_AniMach = CAnimateMachine();
```

And how it is defined

```
CAnimateMachine m_AniMach;
```

Comment: If you do have to use a pointer (for example, polymorphism) you can use `std::unique_ptr`. It will delete the old object when assigned a new one.

Comment: Don't use raw pointers in the first place - you'll cause yourself endless pain, especially coming from a language with GC. Ideally go with juanchopanza's answer, but even if you wanted to use pointers, you should use smart ones. Eg, `std::unique_ptr<CAnimateMachine> m_AniMach;` and `m_AniMach.reset(new CAnimateMachine);` [edit - beaten by @NeilKirk]

Comment: Forget what you know about using C#. C++ is a very different language, and is much better about helping you correctly manage the lifetime of all resources (not just memory). If you're using a CObject class and trying to use dynamically allocated objects in a lot of places, you're fighting against the language. Get a good book like _Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++_ and understand the way C++ does it.

Comment: I wish I had time to read a book on each programming language that I write in, but it just will never happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be no reason to use a pointer. You can use an object instead:

```
CAnimateMachine m_AniMach;
```

in which case it will get default initialized when an object of the type that holds it gets instantiated. To "re-initialize" it, you can say

```
m_AniMach = CAnimateMachine();
```

If you do this, you will not have to worry about things like [following the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) or other dynamic allocation pitfalls.

Comment: this is also much safer than using a pointer, as the object will always be destructed at the end of scope, even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: @AnotherUser That means `CAnimateMachine` is not assignable, so you can't "re-initialize" as I have shown. You will need to find another way of doing that. Without knowing the details of that class, I can't really help.

Comment: Hmm, might I need to write an overloaded `=` operator? // The entire class `CAnimateMAchine` is given above if that helps any?

Comment: @AnotherUser That class definition doesn't match the error. Are you sure it doesn't inherit from, or contain a `CObject`? That is the type that is unassignable.

Comment: Ah, it does contain something referring to `CObject`. I have two pointers in the class, both point to two other classes both derived from `CObject` // Sorry to sound needy/novice but what does this mean, that it holds a `Cobject` pointer, why does that make any difference? // What might I be able to do to fix this?