# Using heap to set value in stack

Tags: c++, class, variables, pointers, stack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the use of 'new' cause memory leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839943/why-does-the-use-of-new-cause-memory-leaks)

I was wondering if,

```
Foo bar = *(new Foo());
```

is okay to do, or am I wasting memory because I cannot delete the the data from the heap after assigning the value to `bar`.

Answer (score 1):

That's an instant memory leak because you lose the reference to it on the heap.

I have to ask though, why would you want to add work for yourself, when you can simply invoke the constructor on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

This works differently as you might expected:

1. you create temporary on the heap which is never destroyed = memory leak
2. you then create COPY of the temporary object on the stack.

So this approach gives you nothing.. Maybe you need [smart pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) there?