# how to free memory after ASSERT_TRUE in gtest

Tags: c++, googletest

I have use case scenario.

```
List* pList = new List();    
for (...)
{

 Integer* pInt = new Integer();
 ASSERT_TRUE(pInt != NULL);
 pList->Add(*pInt);

}
```

Now, should `pInt` be null in any of iteration, then this test case will stop and `pList` will not be freed.

Is there any way to free up `pList` when `ASSERT_TRUE` executes?

Thanks

Comment: The answer to all your resource management: RIIA. Don't ever write `new`/`delete` anymore in modern c++ (except `= delete;`)

Answer (score 3):

If you can use lambdas, you could do:

```cpp
ASSERT_TRUE(pInt != nullptr)
    << [pList]()->std::string { delete pList; return "Your error message."; }();
```

The lambda is only executed if the assertion fails.

However, the best option is probably to use a `std::unique_ptr` or similar smart pointer rather than raw pointers and avoid the worry altogether.

Answer (score 2):

> Now, should `pInt` be null in any of iteration, then this test case will stop and `pList` will not be freed.

Assuming you didn't override the `new` operator (if you did, you probably wouldn't be asking about this), and assuming your compiler is not buggy, `pInt` will never be null. On failure, `new` throws a `std::bad_alloc` exception, it doesn't return null.

Moreover, assertions are for things *that should always hold* (as is the case), no matter what. An assertion failure is *a bug*. There's no point in adding code to clean up after an assertion failure: just fix the bug instead.

Now to the freeing... The sample code provided can just [forget `new` and use automatic objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839943/why-does-the-use-of-new-cause-memory-leaks/8840302#8840302):

```
List pList;
for (...)
{

 Integer pInt = Integer();
 pList.Add(pInt);
}
```