# C++ delete operator with memory locations

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, delete-operator

I am new to C++, and now am studying `new` and `delete` keywords.

```
Point ppaa = *new Point;
Point *p = &ppaa;

ppaa.xpos = 1;
ppaa.ypos= 3;

delete &ppaa;
delete p;
```

Could you please explain why I cannot delete the ppaa above using &ppaa?
I know that delete can only operate on pointer, but I cannot understand why above is not possible since they are actually memory locations. Searching similar questions, it seems that this is related to the copying operations that happen at the first line, but I do not have good explanations.

Comment: You're leaking memory. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839943/why-does-the-use-of-new-cause-memory-leaks/8840302

Comment: Thank Pubbu, it helped a lot. Could you please look into the additional question posted under the Als's answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 T t = x;
```

is known as **Copy Initialization**. It:

- It tries to convert `x` to an object of type `T` &
- Then copies over that object into the to-initialized object `t`.

So your code statement,

```
Point ppaa = *new Point;
```

- Creates a `Point` obejct on freestore/heap and
- then copies that object to create a stack object `ppaa`.

Both these objects are different objects.
As you can see, You do not have any pointer to the heap object anymore after executing this statement.
You need to pass the address returned by `new` to `delete` in this case, Since you do not have the address anymore it results in memory leak.
Further, Note that `&ppaa` does not return the address returned by `new` it returns the address of the object `ppaa` located on the stack. Passing this address to `delete` results in **Undefined Behavior** because `ppaa` was never allocated on freestore/dynamically it is a stack based local/automatic object.

Comment: Thanks very much for your kind explanation. Now I can see how things work in my code! I used c# for a while, so this Copy Initialization is quite interesting to me. Just to be clear, if I write like this in c#(not in c++) : T t1 = new T(); T t2 = t1;  then t2 is just a reference of t1, and there is no copying process as in c++. Am I right?