# C++ what does & do in overloaded assignment operator declaration?

Tags: c++, reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the use of ‘new’ cause memory leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839943/why-does-the-use-of-new-cause-memory-leaks)

What is the difference between (if there is one):

```
   Player player=*(new Player());
```

and:

```
   Player &player=*(new Player());
```

Both (seem to) behave the same way, but I surely miss something?!?

Comment: What they have in common is they share a memory leak :)

Comment: This must have been asked an answered many many times before?

Comment: @Joe: The second one isn't _inherently_ a memory leak, it can be freed properly, if oddly.

Comment: ....and what's wrong with `Player player;`?  :P  Looks like someone's stuck in a Java mindset, unaware that an object can exist without you saying `new`.

Comment: @Joe As [Armen's answer says](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13351496/845092) `delete &player;`

Comment: @cHao Not able to vote your answer up, but your answer was most helpful actually. Thx. C#, BTW. :)

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks, I don't go around taking the address of what a reference is pointing to and deleting them very often (read never).

Comment: Title was changed - not by me. #JustSaying

Comment: Thanks to all, BTW! Very quick - very helpful! Thanks! :)

Comment: @Joe: Oh, I agree.  Such a thing is absolutely foolish and should never be done.  But that's different from impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that the first makes a copy, whereas the second creates a reference to the object pointed to by the pointer returned by `new Player()`.

```
Player player=*(new Player());
```

copy-initializes `player` using the copy-constructor.

```
Player &player=*(new Player());
```

just creates an alias for `*(new Player())`, which is valid because `new Player()` isn't a temporary. `Player& player = Player()` would be illegal because of that.

They're the same in that **they both suck**.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Why does the second suck?

Comment: @mipesom because of the memory leak (and fixing the memory leak is ugly) and because it's not needed. You can simply write `Player player = Player()` to the same effect - no need for `new`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Why on Earth would you write `Player player = Player();` instead of simply writing `Player player;`?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan to guarantee the same effect. If `Player` is a POD type, the latter doesn't initialize the members, while the former does.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I see. It would be strange for a class named `Player` to be a POD type though...

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan it would, but I prefer being thorough. :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Or `Player player{};`, right?

Comment: @sftrabbit C++11 is mostly a mystery to me. :D

Answer (score 2):

`new Player()` is an expression that creates an object (unnamed) on the so-called heap. The result of the expression is a pointer to the newly created object. Now when you do

```
Player player = *(new Player())
```

you define a variable named player that is a **copy** of the newly created object. Moreover, you've lost all handles (access) to the heap object, and you can never free the memory it occupies.

On the other hand,

```
Player &player=*(new Player());
```

creates a **reference** named player to the newly created object. Thus, you have access to that object. In particular, you can free the memory and destroy that object by

```
delete &player;
```

Comment: I was about to write the same thing, but you can actually free the memory in the first case (granted, in an ugly, UGLY way, but still possible).

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: How? You intrigued me :)

Comment: Well, if you have the copy constructor of `Player` hold a reference to the original object, you can delete it in the same way you `delete &player;`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Ah... I thought the trick could be done without touching the Player type...