# deleting a vector

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

If a `vector` contains a bunch of elements that were allocated using `new` and then dereferenced, is the memory for those elements freed when the `vector` is deleted?  For example:

```
vector<Obj> a = *(new vector<Obj>());
a.push_back(*(new Obj()));
delete &a;
```

Is the new `Obj` that was created deallocated?

Comment: You have managed to pack quite a few train wrecks into those 3 lines...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839943/why-does-the-use-of-new-cause-memory-leaks/8840012#8840012

Comment: Just say no to `new`.  And drugs.  But mostly `new`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is all going to go horribly wrong.  Firstly, the assignment on the first line, "a" is on the stack now (not the heap), and the memory allocated by your `new` statement is now lost, leaked, gone.

Secondly, re-occurrance of the same situation.  Obj() will be constructed, and copied.  The memory from your 2nd `new` lost in the depths of space and time, forever.

Then you try and delete an object allocated on the stack.  This is where your program crashes and burns and all that memory loss is inconsequential.

Answer (score 5):

```
vector<Obj> a;
Obj o;
a.push_back(o);
```

Note: no `new` or `delete` in sight. C++ isn't Java.

Answer (score 3):

No; you seem to be having some trouble with ownership in general. In this declaration:

```
vector<Obj> a = *(new vector<Obj>());
```

You are allocating a new `vector`, copying it, then throwing away the original. Since you no longer have a pointer to it, you cannot delete it. This is called a memory leak. Further, this:

```
delete &a;
```

Is undefined behaviour, because you’re not deleting an object allocated via `new`, but rather a local. What you perhaps meant was this:

```
vector<Obj*> a;
// ...
```

That is, allocate a local `vector<Obj>` named `a`, whose storage is automatically reclaimed when it goes out of scope.

Now for your actual question, no, the `vector` only owns the pointers, not the memory to which they point. Consider what would happen otherwise:

```
vector<Obj*> a;
Obj x;
a.push_back(&x);
```

If the `vector` called `delete` on all its pointer elements, then when `a` were destroyed (again, automatically), `x` would also be deleted. Since it was not allocated via `new`, this is undefined behaviour. Luckily, this is not the case!

If you want a vector of pointers which automatically destroy their referents when the `vector` is destroyed, use a vector of `unique_ptr`:

```
vector<unique_ptr<Obj>> a;
a.push_back(unique_ptr(new Obj()));
```

Comment: Pretty solid, except you need `vector<Obj*> a;` in your 4th code snippet if you're going to `push_back()` the *address* of an `Obj` onto it.

Answer (score 0):

No. The `*(new Obj())` statement pushes (into the vector) a copy of the heap-allocated object. The **copied object** (in the vector) is later destroyed (when the vector is destroyed), but the **original heap-allocated Obj object** is never deleted (and the the heap-allocated memory is never freed).

Answer (score 0):

The `vector<Obj> a` part allocates an empty vector on the stack.

`= *(new vector<Obj>());` Allocates another empty vector on the heap and assigns (copies) it to the stack vector. The memory allocated on the heap has no reference and is leaked.

`a.push_back(*(new Obj()));` Allocates an `Obj` on the heap and copies it into the stack vector. The memory allocated on the heap is leaked.

`delete &a;` Tries to delete the vector allocated on the stack which is an error.

Maybe this is what you're trying to do:

```
vector<Obj*>* a = new vector<Obj*>();
a.push_back(new Obj());
delete a;
```

And no, the objects pushed back into the vector will not be deallocated, they will be leaked. When calling delete on the vector pointer `a` it will default deconstruct the vector which does not involve deallocating dynamically allocated memory.

Tip:
Don't use naked pointers, prefer to use **unique_ptr** or **shared_ptr**.

Comment: *"And yes, now the data allocated and pushed into the vector should be deleted when you delete the vector."* -- That sentence is a bit ambiguous.  It could be read as instructing the OP to call delete on the objects in the vector before calling delete on the vector.  But I could also interpret it to mean that calling delete on the vector will result in all the objects being deleted.

Comment: Hmm, you went the wrong way with that.  The allocated objects will *not* be de-allocated, they will be leaked.  I thought that was the reason you suggested using smart pointers.

Comment: Yes you're right. I realise now that the default destructor will only call the destructor on objects, not delete data referenced by pointers. I will correct my answer.