# delete automatic int variable

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am trying to learn the best habits and practices in C++, particularly surrounding memory management. I have been spoiled on this front by using ARC in my iOS apps, and the built-in GC in Java, as well as a few other languages where GC is enabled.

I understand that you use `delete` or `delete[]` to deconstruct pointers. My question is, how do you `delete` integers, or other variables of a base data type?

My first thought was that since `delete` seems to only work with pointers, can I do this:

```
int intToDelete = 6;
delete &intToDelete;
```

So basically, can you create a pointer to an integer in memory, and delete the integer using that pointer?

Comment: You don't delete `intToDelete`. When it goes out of scope, it ceases to exist. Automatically.

Comment: I was going to answer, but then realized I would write something very similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839943/why-does-the-use-of-new-cause-memory-leaks/8840302#8840302).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, I see what you did there.

Comment: Thanks for the REALLY quick answers! I actually just got a book over C++, and everything comes pretty naturally with memory management being the only exception! Thanks again, and sorry for my "beginner's ignorance."

Comment: Your profile says you know Objective-C. Note that this is doing the exact same thing as it does in Objective-C and C - it's just automatic storage on the stack.

Comment: @Pubby Thanks for relating it to something I understand better. I get now that it all depends on the scope of the variable, and unless you allocate something in global memory, it ceases to exist once its scope is no longer relevant. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`delete` and `delete[]` should only be used with pointers which you allocated explicitly with `new` or `new[]`, respectively. In particular, for every time you use `new`, you should have a corresponding `delete`. Similarly, each `new[]` needs a corresponding `delete[]`. You should never use either of these with variables for which you do not explicitly allocate memory. The compiler takes care of memory allocation (and deallocation) for all non-pointer variables.

Answer (score 1):

`delete` is for releasing the memory in heap allocated by `new` operator, and `delete[]` is the counterpart for `new[]`.
You cannot use `delete` to release a pointer which was not allocated by `new`, even a pointer from `malloc`.

Comment: You CAN use delete[] for malloc()-allocated memory in most implementations of C++ because it's just overridden free() for basic types. But it's better not to rely on this.

Answer (score 0):

Local objects clean themselves up automatically. This is one of the most useful features of the language, as it can also be extended through RAII to cover non-local objects. Specifically, the use of `delete` is a *massive* red flag that you did not use the correct automatic cleanup tools, and `delete[]` is even worse.

Correct use of construction and destruction semantics is essential to well-written C++ code. If you're manually managing memory, you're doing it wrong, unless you have a doddering old compiler *or* some very unique circumstances (which I have never, ever seen any examples of that actually justify this).