# IplImage variable overwritten whenever i add into a vector

Tags: pointers, boost

Hi guys i am trying to add an `IplImage` into a vector every time i extract a frame from the camera, but somehow the `IplImage` stored in my vector always got over-written by the latest frame.

The variable that i want to store is `image.get()` with image defined as

```
boost::scoped_ptr<IplImage> image(cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1));
```

i have created a vector to store my image as followed

```
cv::vector< const IplImage*> buffer;
```

i use the function push_back to add in the image into buffer

```
buffer.push_back(image.get());
```

after that i try to save the image as png format for each variable in the buffer and i discover that the images are the same.

i think this should be a pointer issue as i have no problem trying to save integers into another vector.

any suggestion how i can store different images into a vector? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Wait a second. Do you know what `scoped_ptr<>` does?

```
IplImage const* store_this_somewhere; // e.g. in your vector
{
    boost::scoped_ptr<IplImage> image(cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1));

     store_this_somewhere = image.get();

 } // HERE `image` is destructed and **deletes** the image

 // store_this_somewhere is **dangling** here and dereferencing it is 
 // UB
```

I think you're having **[Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)** because the image gets deleted. Next time you grab a screenshot, the memory allocated might happen to be in the same spot which causes the "old", dangling, pointers to seem to point to the latest screen grab.

Either don't use pointers, *or* use smart pointers:

```
cv::vector< boost::scoped_ptr<const IplImage*> > buffer;
```

See also:

- [Why does the use of 'new' cause memory leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839943/why-does-the-use-of-new-cause-memory-leaks/8840302#8840302) (for the art; it might help explain how `scoped_ptr` leaves the pointer dangling)
- [What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)

Very general:

- [What are the barriers to understanding pointers and what can be done to overcome them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome/5754?s=4|0.0000#5754)