# Create new struct, insert into list, re-use pointer, return in vector... whether and how to delete?

Tags: c++, memory-management, scope, new-operator, delete-operator

In C++ code that I wrote to demonstrate an algorithm in an answer, I'm creating structs in a function using `new`, storing them in a list, moving them to a vector, then returning the vector:

```cpp
struct my_struct {int a, b, c;};

std::vector<my_struct> myFunction(...) {
    std::list<my_struct> my_list;
    std::list<my_struct>::iterator current = my_list.begin();
    std::vector<my_struct> my_vector;
    my_struct *new_struct = nullptr;

    while (...) {
        ...
        if (!new_struct) {
            new_struct = new my_struct;
            new_struct->a = ...
        }
        ...
        if (new_struct) {
            new_struct->b = ...
            my_list.insert(current, *my_struct);
            my_struct = nullptr;
        }
        ...
        if (...) {
            current->c = ...
            my_vector.push_back(*current);
            current = my_list.erase(current);
        }
        ...
    }
    return my_vector;
}
```

It compiles and seems to work correctly, however I'm more used to JavaScript and this code just feels like translated JavaScript; I'm specifically wondering whether I'm creating memory leaks, and whether I have to delete the structs in the calling function (and how).

Comment: AFAIK, `typedef struct (int a, b, c;) my_struct;` is not valid syntax. It's also closer to C than C++

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the use of 'new' cause memory leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839943/why-does-the-use-of-new-cause-memory-leaks)

Comment: Note that in this case, allocating memory on the heap for your struct is completely unnecessary. You should just allocate the struct directly on the stack, and possibly use `std::move` when you insert the elements.

Comment: Avoid using naked `new`/`delete`. Always (almost; there are *rare* exceptions) use smart pointers instead.

Comment: JavaScript and C++ are *very* different languages. You can't translate what you know about one to the other - even if they seem to have somewhat similar syntax in some cases, identical constructs may (and do) mean completely different things.

Comment: The code is not valid C++ (or C, for that matter).   Try providing a small representative sample of actual C++ which actually represents what yo are trying to do.   In general terms, however, if you are storing instances of a `my_struct` in a `std::vector<my_struct>` your code will not need to use pointers at all, and will not need to explicitly use operators `new` and `delete`.

Comment: @Justin I was going to accept your duplicate suggestion, but I made a small edit to my question, and now I no longer get the "This answered my question" option, not even after undoing the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others in the question section have already pointed out, you probably shouldn't use `new` at all. The only reason to use pointers there at all is the `if(newstruct)` checks, if they are an essential part of your algorithm.

But if you use `new`, you should delete, too. It's safe to do that after inserting the struct into the list or vector - the list and vector contain copies.

Comment: The if(new_struct) checks were indeed part of the reason I wrote it like that. I guess I'll have to rethink that part, and use an extra variable.

Comment: @m69: Using an extra variable to determine whether another object "exists" or "is valid" is a pattern so common that C++ now supports it (or something very similar) as part of the standard library, see my answer about `std::optional`.

Comment: It was actually when trying to use delete() after inserting the struct into the list, and getting errors, that I became confused and posted this question. I just realized that I forgot to reset the pointer to nullptr after calling delete(), expecting delete() to do that automatically.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you have a memory leak. If you invoke the `new` command, you will need to invoke a `delete` command in the future to free the memory allocated by `new`.

So, in this statement:

```
my_list.insert(current, *my_struct);
```

you are indeed copy the contents of `*my_struct`, not getting the ownership of it. So, in the following statement:

```
my_struct = nullptr;
```

You just got a memory leak.

To solve this, change your design to use smartpointer, for example, unique_ptr, or, better yet, dont use pointer at all, and just use a plain object:

```
my_struct new_struct;
```

Comment: So a (possible, not ideal) fix would be to use a list and vector of pointers to struct, return this, and then delete the structs using the pointers in the calling function?

Comment: I dont know if I get it what you want correctly, but using a vector of pointer is not good. You need to be sure that every exit path on your program that want to dispose the object get a call to delete or you will get a memory leak. If you really want to use a pointer, much better if you use a smartpointer, which will do this memory management for you, for free

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with C++17, [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) (and before that, `boost::optional`) is a sensible alternative solution for your specific problem here. It removes the need for pointers and the danger of memory leaks but at the same time still gives you a "nothing" state.

Your pseudo code would become something like:

```
// this is the correct way of defining a struct in C++:
struct my_struct {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

std::vector<my_struct> myFunction(...) {
    std::list<my_struct> my_list;
    std::list<my_struct>::iterator current = my_list.begin();
    std::vector<my_struct> my_vector;
    std::optional<my_struct> new_struct; // new_struct does not hold a value

    while (...) {
        ...
        if (!new_struct.has_value()) { // if it does not hold a value...
            new_struct = my_struct(); // it holds a value now (a default my_struct)
            new_struct->a = ... // access syntax like a pointer
        }
        ...
        if (new_struct.has_value()) {
            new_struct->b = ...
            my_list.insert(current, *new_struct); // dereference syntax like a pointer
            new_struct.reset(); // it no longer holds a value now
        }
        ...
        if (...) {
            current->c = ...
            my_vector.push_back(*current);
            current = my_list.erase(current);
        }
        ...
    }
    return my_vector;
}
```

Note how the *syntax* of `std::optional` deliberately mimics that of pointers.

Comment: This indeed looks like it was specifically invented to solve my problem :-)