# Dynamic memory allocation using struct

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to understand the concept of dynamic memory allocation. I have written some code that dynamically allocates an array of structs. The struct name is data and contains name and roll number. It asks user how many times you want to enter. After entering data it is supposed to search the data according to roll number. It crashes when searching for a particular roll number. Below is the code.

```
struct data
    {
        char name[50];
        int roll; float cgpa; char camp[3]; 

    };
    int main()
    {

        data *p;

        int i;
        cout << "how many times you want to enter data? "; cin >> i;
        p = new data[i];

        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)

        {

            cout << "Enter your name:";
            cin >> p[k].name;

            cout << "Enter your roll number:";
            cin >> p[k].roll;

            cout << endl<<endl;
            p++;
        }
        int r;
        cout << "enter roll number to search for :"; cin >> r;
        for (int j = 0; i < i; j++){

        if (p[j].roll == r)
        {
            cout << "Roll number:" << p[j].roll << endl; cout << "Name:" << p[j].name << endl;

        }
        else{
            cout << "Not found!" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
        delete []p;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The simplest way to do things is probably to use `std::vector`.

Comment: 4 times the same text ?

Comment: I couldn't ask question because of  too small explanation of code so that's why i have to copy paste it 4 times kindly ignore it.

Comment: You should ask question properly instead of doing such a dirty hack. It hurts yourself.

Comment: @user463035818    Actually i don't find it to be a serious problem you should all be concern of code rather than of  text.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf i am not familiar with vectors

Comment: Wrong, Both text and code are important.

Comment: @MuzahirHussnain: If you can, choose a book that teaches `std:.vector` up front. E.g. "Accelerated C++". See the C++ book list here on SO. Also, tip, you can use free tools such as AStyle to properly format your code before posting. Please do that in future.

Comment: @NickyC  Yeah it might be but in this case you can interpret what i am asking for can't you??Wouldn't it be great if you can deal with this problem rather than to taunt.Come up with some solution to this.

Comment: @MuzahirHussnain code only question arent very usefull either. Anyhow, text has been fixed and I can remove my previous comment

Comment: just to let you know why i didnt retract my close vote: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Comment: @user463035818 Thank you for fixing  it.I appreciate you for this.

Comment: i didnt fix anything, you edited the text, no?

Comment: Yeah I might be able to interpret what you are asking. But wouldn't it be nice if you ask question properly rather than visually obscure fellows on the internet from helping you??? Show some decency.

Comment: @NickyC truly  said...

Comment: @MuzahirHussnain There are a lot of questions at SO, and people are using their own time to answer them. It's basic courtesy  to make your question as clear as possible. Code formatting matters. Explanation matters. Related, when experienced programmers think code formatting is important for being able to work efficiently, I wonder why many novices think they are better and don't need well formatted code?

Comment: @hyde Okay, i got it what you are actually trying to convey i will take care of it in future and sorry for the inconvenience to all who are concerned about it.I apologize.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf i was not refering to the code but rather to the "must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error " part. However, I take your critic serious and I have to admit my vote really was not justified at all.

Comment: That's an ok-ish question. Maybe a specific error message would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

In this code:

```
for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)   

{

    cout << "Enter your name:";
    cin >> p[k].name;

    cout << "Enter your roll number:";
    cin >> p[k].roll;

    cout << endl<<endl;
    p++;
}
```

You are incrementing the pointer to access and the index to access the pointer from so you going to far in memory.

Either iterate by index or by pointer/iterator.

Answer (score -1):

p is the array. It points to the start of the data reserved by new Data[i].

As soon as you increment it, it doesn't point to the start anymore.

Just drop the increment p++ statement and it'll work.

By the way there is no need to delete it at the end of main. It'll be freed anyway.

Comment: _"By the way there is no need to delete it at the end of main. It'll be freed anyway."_ Really?

Comment: @acraig5075: Yes. But depending on the context that might cause a report of leaking memory.

Comment: if the data is allocated only once in the whole program and no allocation will ever be performed after the data should be freed you don't need to free BUT its a bad habit and there is no reason not to free

Comment: I would argue not freeing memory and deferring deallocation to program termination are two different things, even if the generated machine code are the same.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, @Tyker, @NickyC - See [why does the use of new cause memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839943/why-does-the-use-of-new-cause-memory-leaks). Also, I recommend  you read a beginners book on C++, such as [Stroustrup's Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++](https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Principles-Practice-Using-2nd/dp/0321992784/ref=dp_ob_title_bk?dpID=51j679vpDGL&preST=_SX218_BO1,204,203,200_QL40_&dpSrc=detail) which very clearly states on p. 600 that not using `delete` **causes a memory leak.** You usually should not rely on OS-freeing.

Comment: @Tellus: We were discussing the facts of the OP's code, not general recommendations. Also do note that memory leaks are not always negative: leaking memory can be an intentional choice for efficiency. It all depends.

Comment: Wow! Back in 90s i developed an interpreter to parse a simple command script. It used only new() and not a single delete without leaking memory. I used a static memory buffer and overloaded the new operator. BTW That's not beginners level anyway.