# error in type T contructor | do I need address constructor? no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘abc<int>’ and ‘abc<int>*’)

Tags: c++

I am creating template class for vector from standard library in C++. And I am getting error at this line

```
arr[i]=new T(_px,_py,_pz);
```

above line is inside constructor of `vectorClass`.

this is the code of `vectorClass`

```
vectorClass(J _px[],J _py[],J _pz[],int cap)
           {
               arr= (T *)malloc(cap*sizeof (T));
               for(int i=0;i<cap;i++)
                   arr[i]=new T(_px,_py,_pz);//error line

               std::cout<<"vectorClass(J _px,J _py,_J _px,cap) called"<<std::endl;
               T(_px,_py,_pz);
               //how to allocated cap sized T arr[cap] and assign it to arr

           }
```

`arr` is declared as `T* arr;`

in the note of conpiler is says

```
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘abc<int>*’ to ‘const abc<int>&’
```

Does the above error tells about that I need constructor in `template abc` that accepts address of `this` like

```
      abc(this& ?) //?what should be the name? its just (this)
```

this is my full code

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>



template <typename T> class abc{
private:
    abc *p;
    T *px=x;
    T *py=y;
    T *pz=z;
    int capacity=10;
    int current1=0;
public:
    //these members must be included
    T x[10]={};
    T y[10]={};
    T z[10]={};

    abc(const T _px[],const T _py[],const T _pz[]):x{{10}},y{{10}},z{{10}}
    {

        std::cout<<"--->  abc(_px,_py,_pz) called"<<std::endl;
        memcpy(x,_px,sizeof (T));
        memcpy(y,_py,sizeof (T));
        memcpy(z,_pz,sizeof (T));

    }


    int writetoHW()
    {
        //member write to hardware...x,y,z... linux socket, mmap and other work
        return 0;
    }
};

template <class T>

class vectorClass
 {
    T* arr;
    int capacity=10;
    int current=0;

        public:



           //in main user will pass three arrays
           template<class J>
           vectorClass(J _px[],J _py[],J _pz[],int cap)
           {
               arr= (T *)malloc(cap*sizeof (T));
               for(int i=0;i<cap;i++)
                   arr[i]=new T(_px,_py,_pz);//error line
//                   test.cpp:57:26: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘abc<int>’ and ‘abc<int>*’)
//test.cpp:7:29: note: candidate: ‘constexpr abc<int>& abc<int>::operator=(const abc<int>&)’
               std::cout<<"vectorClass(J _px,J _py,_J _px,cap) called"<<std::endl;
               T(_px,_py,_pz);
               //how to allocated cap sized T arr[cap] and assign it to arr

           }
           vectorClass(int x){}

            void push_back(T t)
            {

                T *temp;

                //arr=new T[++capacity];//how to increase the size of arr by one with ...(T t)
                //temp[capacity] = t;

                //for (int i = 0; i < capacity + 1; ++i){
                  //  arr[i] = temp[i];
                //}

                delete [] temp;
                
            }

          

            /*
            REST of the class remains the same
            */
 };


int main()
{

    int a1[3]={1,1,1};
    //const abc<int> a2(a1,a1,a1);
    vectorClass<abc<int>> o(a1,a1,a1,3);
    //a.push_back(a2);
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: *"this is my full code"* -- please don't post your full code when a [mre] is adequate.

Comment: @JaMiT error is gone why why I can't use second template. what seem to be a problem? I have any type of `abc` and any type of vectorClass.

Comment: Oh, right. When you do `new T(_px,_py,_pz)`, you assume that `T` is an instantiation of the `abc` template, even though that is not documented (and it is not suggested by the syntax). OK, I retract my second comment, as I let myself be confused by the lack of separation between your templates (not good design, but also not the reason for your error).

Comment: @JaMiT then what is correct design of separation of two template? Can u please explain a bit or refer me to something

Comment: @JaMiT its been fixed. check my answer

Comment: *"what is correct design of separation of two template?"* -- Your `vectorClass` should make no assumptions about how `T` is constructed. Currently it assumes that a `T` object can be constructed from three arrays of any type, provided the three arrays are of the same type as each other.

Comment: @JaMiT `Oh, right. When you do new T(_px,_py,_pz), you assume that T is an instantiation of the abc template, even though that is not documented (and it is not suggested by the syntax)` can u share a link to that explanation is it available on  en.cppreference.com I like to see the full explanation. can u please do this?

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it. now my vectorClass constructor is like this \

```
template <class J>
           vectorClass( J _px[],J _py[], J _pz[],int cap)
           {
               arr= (T *)malloc(cap*sizeof (T));
               for(int i=0;i<cap;i++)
                   arr[i]=*(new T(_px,_py,_pz));//error line not any more

               std::cout<<"vectorClass(J _px,J _py,_J _px,cap) called"<<std::endl;
               T(_px,_py,_pz);
               //how to allocated cap sized T arr[cap] and assign it to arr

           }
```

and I had to include construtor this takes address of `this`

```
  abc(T& obj)
    {
      this=obj;
    }
```

Comment: You've introduced a memory leak, and your "construtor this takes address of `this`" does not compile. Don't just mindlessly slap code together until it compiles.

Comment: @JaMiT `memory leak` because I am not adding distructor. Is this why memory leak?

Comment: [Why does the use of 'new' cause memory leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839943)

Comment: @JaMiT thanks for ur comment so that means there is no way I can store this  `*(new T(_px,_py,_pz));` so later on cleanup I can free it from memory delete it. or is there any how I can store it?

Comment: I like this idea if I implement `=` operator in template `abc` and create destructor in template `vectorClass` do u think then this will be fixed and no leak will happen 
or do I also need to create destructor in template `abc`  as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/8840007/4808760

Comment: I think these questions are going well beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: I asked a new question. Now I am more interested in handling resource in class/T class I asked a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68790150/operator-overloading-of-needs-return-obj-or-this-obj-in-c-in-code-for?noredirect=1#comment121572166_68790150