# what does the *new operator in c++ do?

Tags: c++, object, pointers, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

if I have the following -

```
#include <iostream>

class object{
    private:
    public:
       object();
       object(some_item);
};


object a;

int main()
{
   // why doesn't it let me do
   a = new object(some_item);
   
   // but lets me do
   a = *new object(some_item);
   
}
```

I am trying to initialize a global object which will be initialized at runtime inside the main loop but not in the part where I defined it globally.

basically I want an object that is available globally and that can be initialized at runtime inside any function.

But I don't completely understand how the new/*new operator works.

Comment: `a = *new object(some_item);` is just a memory leak. operator `new` is used for dynamic allocations (and therefore returns a pointer), which is not what you want here at all

Comment: You don't even need the new. That object is already created an initialized.

Comment: You want a disaster waiting to happen. Globals should typically be `constexpr`, or read-only state. The code as shown also doesn't need `new` at all.

Comment: `new` returns a pointer to a dynamic allocation.  `object a;` provides a `object`, not a pointer to an `object`.

Comment: Strong recommendation: This will be beaten to death fairly early in any [non-fraudulent textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/4581301), so consider getting and reading one.

Comment: If you want to do it the hard way, though, [here's a great documentation page on `new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new).

Comment: @UnholySheep I first read that as "memory leak operator" and I refuse to put it out of my head.

Comment: There is no `*new` operator, what you have done is `*(new object(some_item))`, which is a memory leak (unless you have some hidden mechanism for saving a pointer to the object and freeing it later).  Hint: remove the `*` and remove the `new`.

Comment: What happens with `a = *new object(some_item);` space for a `object` is allocated from the freestore and a `object` is constructed in that memory. The pointer to the `object` is then dereferenced to get the  pointed-at `object` and this `object` copied into the already existing `object` `a`. The pointer is never stored, so the dynamically allocated `object` is lost, also known as "leaked" and exceptionally hard to locate and later destroy and return to the freestore with `delete`.

Comment: *and that can be initialized at runtime inside any function.* -- Too late.  It has already been initialized when you declared `object a;`

Comment: *But I don't completely understand how the `new` operator works.*  Using `new` is an advanced technique, which you shouldn't worry about until you've been programming in C++ for over a year.  I've been programming in C++ for 34 years, and I haven't used `new` in real code in the last 10 years, since there are much better alternatives than using the (as I'm now forever going to call it) **memory leak operator**.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I've got it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839943/why-does-the-use-of-new-cause-memory-leaks

Comment: I wish we had a `novice` or `beginner` tag.  This is a **good** novice or beginner question, that other novices/beginners could find useful.

Comment: You should avoid writing `new` whenever possible. If you must heap-allocate, use `std::make_unique<T>()` then you’d have `a = *std::make_unique<object>(some_item);` which at least won’t leak. Although better is `a = object(some_item);`.

Answer (score 4):

`operator new` returns a pointer to a dynamically created object.

So, the type of this expression:

```
new object(some_item)
```

is the pointer type `object *`.

On the other hand, the variable `a` is declared as having the type `object`:

```
object a;
```

So, you are trying to assign a pointer of the type `object *` to an object of the type `object`:

```
a = new object(some_item);
```

and within the class `object`, there is no overloaded assignment `operator=` declared like this:

```
object & operator =( object * );
```

So, the compiler issues an error.

However, when the pointer expression is dereferenced, then you get an object reference of the type `object&` , and can assign it to the variable `a`:

```
a = *new object(some_item);
```

using the default generated copy assignment `operator=`.

Pay attention to that, in this case, you will have a memory leak, because the address of the dynamically allocated `object` will be lost.

If you want to have a dynamically allocated object, or an array of objects, then the variable `a` should have the pointer type `object *`:

```
object *a;
```

In this case, you may write in `main()`:

```
a = new object(some_item);
```

And then you have to free it when you are done using it:

```
delete a;
```

Comment: Object created with ```new``` needs to be manually deleted after using. ```Object *o = new Object( arguments); // do something with o; delete o;```